# To "turn a blind eye"

Tags: idiom

What would be the German equivalent for this English idiom?

In the situation when one sees something they'd have rather not seen and chooses to "ignore" it.

Comment: Which dictionaries have you already consulted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> (nochmals) ein Auge zudrücken

is in frequent use. I am however not sure if it matches exactly the English phrase as I am not acquainted enough with it. *Nochmals ein Auge zudrücken* or *Da will ich mal eine Auge zudrücken* is used for situations when somebody (usually a person of authority, or somebody who is able to decide something) has gotten knowledge of something negative (relating to somebody else), but decides to ignore it.

Sample situations:

- Conductor in a tram spots a person without a ticket, however, the person has a good excuse (or the conductor feels pity), and so: *Na gut, da drücke ich nochmals ein Auge zu."
- Apprentice coming late to work excuses himself with something like his girlfriend had 20th birthday last night. Master: *Na gut, dann will ich nochmals ein Auge zudrücken. Aber dass das nicht beim 30. wieder passiert!*

Comment: Why do you answer such an off-topic question?

Comment: @infinitezero why do you consider this question off-topic?

Comment: @Christian From the description in the question I'd say that #1 or #3 of the answers in the link from c.p. are best fitting. Your suggestion would mean "to forgive"/"chose not to punish" rather than "to ignore".

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf because this site is "not a substitute for a dictionary or a conjugation table", also no research effort. It might be a wrong rule, but within the scope as defined by the current rules it makes the question OT

Comment: But the OP did not ask for a simple translation of a single word, easy to find in any dictionary (in that case I would agree to "off-topic"). He asked for a complete idiom (Redewendung) and gave a description of the situation when to say it.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf single words are not exactly different than idioms in this regard. Especially if we compare compound words, which are written in one word in German, and in two words - in English. Both single words and idioms can be found in a generic dictionary; and there are a lot of elaborate collocations dictionaries online, one of them being dict.cc Besides, the offtopic rule simply says that this site is not a substitute to a dictionary, and doesn't mention "single word translations".